# Coloring within random irregular shape of an UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors, uiimage, uibezierpath

I am working on a coloring app and want to achieve something like this app [here](https://apps.apple.com/my/app/toonia-colourbook-colour-inside/id633956731)

I was able to fill color within the edges of a particular shape but when it comes to coloring I am not able to stop the coloring beyond the edges of a particular shape.

Let's take this shape image as example. [image]
<sub>(source: [storyplace.org](http://www.storyplace.org/preschool/images/shapes/shapespieces.gif))</sub>

I want to color the star. Here is what I am doing right now.
1. Using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to recognise the starting point.
2. Creating `UIBezierPath` for the star shape.
3. Detecting touches if they are within the star shape with `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` state for `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
4. If it is inside then draw the line else ignore.

But the `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` does not get called continuously for every movement due to which I am not able to get the expected behaviour.

Kindly advise how can it be done.

Comment: Check out touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded.

Comment: I tried and even that does not called continuously.

Comment: i don't get it. You want to paint as you move your finger? Or just fill shape with a color on touch? The last case should be fairly simple. Just check if touches ended was within your shape and run a "flood fill" algorithm.

Comment: I have implemented the flood fill algorithm and it works fine. But when it comes to coloring, it should only color inside that particular area. If the touches go out, it should not color.